# Why I can't import this module?

Tags: python, keras, importerror

I'm trying to import `img_to_array` even though all packages are there. This error still appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Usuario\Downloads\keras-api\keras-main.py", line 11, in <module> from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array 

ImportError: cannot import name 'img_to_array' from 'keras.preprocessing.image'
```

This is how I am calling the packages from the `keras` package.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
```

On the other hand, this is what I'm trying to do with the code.

```
image = img_to_array(image)
```

However, I cannot even continue because I'm not able to import `img_to_array`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'img\_to\_array' from 'keras.preprocessing.image'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72334642/importerror-cannot-import-name-img-to-array-from-keras-preprocessing-image)

Answer (score 1):

but this is how you import `img_to_array` if you have installed the `keras` package via e.g. `pip install keras`

```
from keras.utils import img_to_array
img_to_array
```

check if the `keras` version is the correct one:
[Keras Installation Guide](https://github.com/keras-team/keras#installation)